# How can I automatically compile all directive dependency?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

Lets say I make two Angular directives:

Foo:

```
<div> Hello World! </div>
```

Bar:

```
<foo></foo>
```

I now want to test `Bar`. My test will look something along the lines of:

```
describe("Bar Test", function () {
    beforeEach(
        angular.mock.module('module')
    );

    var $rootscope,
    $compile,
    element,
    scope;

    beforeEach(inject(['$injector', function ($injector) {
        $rootscope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
        scope = $rootscope.$new();
        element = $compile(angular.element('<bar></bar>'))(scope);

        var $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        var html = require('text!path/to/bar.html');
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/bar.html/).respond(html);
        scope.$apply();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }]));

    it("test bar", function(){
        expect(element.find("foo").text).toEqual("Hello World!");
    });
});
```

Now this example is a little silly as the `Bar` test is really testing `Foo`, but when you can imagine the directives getting more complex and the behavior becomes more intertwined (ie lets say `Foo` creates an object on `Bar`'s scope)

This example also wont work, as `Foo` never got compiled, so `Bar`'s inner html will just be `<foo></foo>`, with no Hello World inside.

My question is: **How do I get my unit test to automatically compile all dependent directives in my unit test?**

I suspect the answer might be 'you shouldn't do that because then its not a unit test', so alternatively, how do I explicitly allow specific directives to get compiled?

Comment: This is what should be avoided in unit tests, 'the behavior becomes more intertwined (ie lets say Foo creates an object on Bar's scope)'. Units are tested in isolation and aren't intertwined. Save this for e2e. Also, `$compile` **does** compile all element hierarchy, that's how it works, seek the problem elsewhere (e.g. `text` is used instead of `text()`).